# How to close a thread in die2nite forums?

Tags: die2nite

Does the Crow do that or...? How does it work?
I've posted a distress call, I've been rescued, and now I'm looking for a "close thread" button/link/anything, and can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you are back in town after posting a distress call, the thread will automatically close.

For normal threads, the creator has the option of closing the thread.

Comment: @user7963: If an answer adequately answers your question, then consider accepting it by clicking the green check-mark under the score. It'll let people know that that's the right answer, and give you both some rep, and is even better than just saying thank you. :)